# Guess the song and artist

Tags: music

\begin{array}{l}
&19\times 46=784\\
&56+43=102\\
&360\div 15=29\\
&196-55=114\\
\end{array}

> **Hint 1:** For once, this is *not* an abuse of the equals symbol!
>  **Hint 2:** The clues are  for the song only, the artist follows.
>  **Hint 3:** $26 + 89 = 115$
>  **Hint 4:** The third equation is potentially paradoxical, but I don't mind.
>  **Hint 5:** Released as a single (B side) in 1696!

Comment: Are all the equations clues to one answer? Or is each a different answer

Comment: @orp all one answer

Comment: If it's not an abuse of the equals symbol, why are the results not $874$, $99$, $25$, and $141$ respectively?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I think you might mean $ 874, 99, 24,$ and $141\dots$ but you will have to guess the answer to see why!

Comment: Well, I can make the maths work, but I'm not particularly familiar with the music of that era... but I guess I can't always get what I want.

Comment: @Alconja you were nearly there, but Petter beat you to it!

Comment: All good. :) I had a bit of a google and found nothing that seemed to fit (hence my hinted "you can't always get what you want", which was a b-side track from '69). If I had've stumbled across the song in the solution I'd have known for sure... but I guess my google-fu is not up to scratch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> *If 6 was 9* by Jimi Hendrix

Explanation

> The numbers 6 and 9 have been switched in the equations, meaning that any 6 is actually a 9, and any 9 is a 6. Thus the equations turn into
>
>  \begin{array}{l} &16\times 49=784\\&59+43=102\\&390\div 15=26\\&169-55=114\\\end{array}
>  Which are valid equations!

Explanation of hints

> **Hint 3** becomes $29 + 86 = 115$ (though it was correct even before switching)
>  **Hint 4** "I don't mind" are lyrics from the song *If 6 was 9*
>  **Hint 5** The song was released in 1969
>  The other hints don't need explanation

Comment: well done! I thought I was going to have to give another hint! :)

Comment: note  the answer to eq. three: $26\rightarrow 29$

Comment: Thanks! I thought the "paradoxical" thing should have some meaning, but I couldn't think of anything there :) Will need to mull it over a bit more!

Comment: Ah, got it now, will edit it in, thanks!